# User ask for difference between two constructs where one isn't valid - Is flagging or voting to close appropriate?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, vote-to-close

What if a user ask for the difference between two programming constructs but one of those isn't even valid in the tagged language.

Is a flag or vote to close appropriate here? And if yes, Which one?

I thought about closing it as "Needs details or clarity" or eventually "Needs Debugging Details" but I'm not sure. VLQ also came to mind.

Or is a downvote the only tool I can use here?

Comment: No, it's just a bad poorly researched question.

Comment: @Gimby So just downvoting?

Comment: Post a comment asking, "Did you really mean <construct B>? That's a syntax error!". If they don't respond, downvote & VTC as unclear.

Comment: @PM2Ring I found such a question as example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63386089/12139179). It was commented and already got an answer that it is wrong but OP didn't reacted even after 10 hours (current stand). So, Voting to close as "Needs details or clarity" is appropriate?

Comment: Ok, that's an edge case. In isolation, the 1st construct is bogus, but as the comment by dbush & the answer by eric point out, that form *is* valid in a function parameter declaration, although of course a function parameter declaration must not end in a semicolon. Personally, I wouldn't worry too much about that question, since it has attracted a nice answer that may be useful to both the OP & future readers. But if people want to downvote it, or VTC it as unclear, I wouldn't stop them. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring That's just an example. My thinking is what is in a generic kind of view appropriate in such case when I find something like that again? Just downvoting or flagging or close?

Comment: Generically, my answer is what I said in my 1st comment. Another option is to VTC as a typo. I like to give OPs constructive feedback, if it looks like they've made some effort to post a decent question, and they respond to feedback. IMHO, it's better to help the OP to turn a bad question into a good one, than to just close it. OTOH, if the OP can't be bothered to make an effort, why should we?

Comment: Some will argue that the point of closing faulty questions is to give the OP the opportunity to repair the question and to stop low grade answers from appearing before the question is fixed. But if a question only has a minor flaw, I feel it's better to get it fixed quickly & not close the question, since closed questions have a high probability of getting abandoned.

Comment: @PM2Ring I appreciate your argumentation. Yes, that's correct. I also like to give OP the chance to alter their mistakes. But maybe if the question is abandoned like in this case, the vote to close is appropriate because it's also a frustration for someone who answers if you got not feedback at all and just have an left OP.